# Get provider injected with key in a NetJS Test

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-testing

I have a provider which I inject using a key:

```js
export const myProvider = {
    provide: SOME_PROVIDER,
    useFactory: () => {
      return SomeWrappedInstance;
    },
  };
```

In my tests I want to access this provider which I inject with `@Inject(SOME_PROVIDER)`, how can I do this?

```js
const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [myProvider]
    }).compile();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's easy as doing:

```
const myProviderValue = moduleRef.get(SOME_PROVIDER)
//    ^? SomeWrappedInstance
```